# StackOverflowError when pushing a object to Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase Realtime Database crashes `java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB` when I try to push a `BankAccount` object. I've already replaced all object variables by `Strings` and excluded the `getSubcategoryByName` method but nothing of that helped.

```
private long amount;
private String description;
private String subcategoryName, primaryCategoryName;
private long creationDate;
private int type;

private boolean autoPayBill;

public Bill(){ }

public Bill(long amount, String description, String subcategoryName, String primaryCategoryName, int type, boolean autoPayBill, long creationDate) {
    this.amount = amount;
    this.description = description;
    this.subcategoryName = subcategoryName;
    this.primaryCategoryName = primaryCategoryName;
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
    this.autoPayBill = autoPayBill;
    this.type = type;
}

public Bill(long amount, String description, int type, boolean autoPayBill, String subcategoryName, String primaryCategoryName) {
    this.amount = amount;
    this.description = description;
    this.subcategoryName = subcategoryName;
    this.primaryCategoryName = primaryCategoryName;
    this.type = type;
    this.autoPayBill = autoPayBill;
    creationDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

public long getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public void setAmount(long amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}

public boolean isAutoPayBill() {
    return autoPayBill;
}

public void setAutoPayBill(boolean autoPayBill) {
    this.autoPayBill = autoPayBill;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String descriptions) {
    this.description = descriptions;
}

public Subcategory getSubcategory() {
    return getSubcategoryByName();
}

public void setSubcategory(Subcategory subcategory) {
    this.subcategoryName = subcategory.getName();
}

public String getSubcategoryName() {
    return subcategoryName;
}

public void setSubcategoryName(String subcategoryName) {
    this.subcategoryName = subcategoryName;
}

public String getPrimaryCategoryName() {
    return primaryCategoryName;
}

public void setPrimaryCategoryName(String primaryCategoryName) {
    this.primaryCategoryName = primaryCategoryName;
}

public long getCreationDate() {
    return creationDate;
}

public void setCreationDate(long creationDate) {
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
}

public int getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(int type) {
    this.type = type;
}

@Exclude
private Subcategory getSubcategoryByName(){
    for (PrimaryCategory primaryCategory:Database.getPrimaryCategories()){
        if (primaryCategory.getName().equals(primaryCategoryName)){
            for (Subcategory subcategory:primaryCategory.getSubcategories()){
                if (subcategory.getName().equals(subcategoryName)){
                    return subcategory;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Couldn't find subcategory by name!");
}
```

}

This is the `BankAccount` class which has an `ArrayList` variable which holds all `Bills`.

public class BankAccount {

```
private String name;

private long balance; //In cents

private ArrayList<Bill> bills;

private boolean primaryAccount;

private long creationDate;

private ArrayList<BalanceChange> balanceChanges;

public BankAccount(){

}

public BankAccount(String name, long balance, boolean primaryAccount, long creationDate) {
    this.name = name;
    this.balance = balance;
    this.primaryAccount = primaryAccount;
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
    bills = new ArrayList<>();
    balanceChanges = new ArrayList<>();
}

public BankAccount(String name, long balance, boolean primaryAccount) {
    this.name = name;
    this.balance = balance;
    this.primaryAccount = primaryAccount;
    creationDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
    bills = new ArrayList<>();
    balanceChanges = new ArrayList<>();
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void addBill(Bill bill) {
    if (bill.getType() == Bill.TYPE_INPUT){
        setBalance(getBalance() + bill.getAmount());
} else if(bill.getType() == Bill.TYPE_OUTPUT){
        setBalance(getBalance() - bill.getAmount());
    }

    bills.add(bill);
    balanceChanges.add(new BalanceChange(System.currentTimeMillis(), this.getBalance()));

}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public long getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void setBalance(long balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}

public ArrayList<Bill> getBills() {
    return bills;
}

public void setBills(ArrayList<Bill> bills) {
    this.bills = bills;
}

public boolean isPrimaryAccount() {
    return primaryAccount;
}

public void setPrimaryAccount(boolean primaryAccount) {
    this.primaryAccount = primaryAccount;
}

public long getCreationDate() {
    return creationDate;
}

public void setCreationDate(long creationDate) {
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
}

public ArrayList<BalanceChange> getBalanceChanges() {
    return balanceChanges;
}

public void setBalanceChanges(ArrayList<BalanceChange> balanceChanges) {
    this.balanceChanges = balanceChanges;
}
```

}

And how the Objects are pushed to Firebase

```
    public void createServerBackup(ArrayList<BankAccount> bankAccounts){
        DatabaseReference bankAccountsReference = userReference.child(BANK_ACCOUNTS_REFERENCE);
        bankAccountsReference.setValue(bankAccounts);
}
```

Comment: I guess you have infinite reference loop somewhere. Post `BankAccount` object and how you save it.

Comment: @nikis this is how I save it `public void createServerBackup(ArrayList<BankAccount> bankAccounts){
            DatabaseReference bankAccountsReference = userReference.child(BANK_ACCOUNTS_REFERENCE);
            bankAccountsReference.setValue(bankAccounts);
    }`

Comment: Please edit your question by adding the code that you are using to add the `bankAccounts` to the database and also please responde with @.

Comment: @niks I have now edited my question

Comment: Obvious question: How big is the data you are trying to save exactly?

Comment: At the moment it's one `BankAccount` object which contains one `Bill`